# vim: keep a view (folding settings, cursor,..) from a file to a copied one

Tags: vim

I'm using mkview to save my folding settings, cursor position, etc.. in what is called a view (actually I'm using a plugin that does it automatically, restore_view).

The problem comes when I copy a file, for instance for a backup, I would like to keep that view for that file but it's lost in the new one.

How could I copy that vim "views"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is stored in a file (cp. `:help :mkview`) that is usually stored in the `'viewdir'` location. The file name contains (in somewhat encoded form) the original file's filespec.

If you want to re-use the original file's view in the copy, you have to copy the corresponding view file, too (adapting the file name and path in the same way as with the original).

Alternatively, you can explicitly `:mkview /path/to/tempfile` for the original file and then, after `:edit backupcopy-file`, restore that view via `:source /path/to/tempfile`.